# How to show image icon instead of text in ToggleButton in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

This is the XAML code for a simple toggle button in Windows Phone 8.1.

```
<ToggleButton Content="Text_Here" />
```

How can we show an icon for the same Toggle Button??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ToggleButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.togglebutton.aspx) has [ContentPresenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentpresenter) inside - you can put most of things into it for example icon:

```
<ToggleButton>
     <SymbolIcon Symbol="Message"/>
</ToggleButton>
```

or *Image* if you want:

```
<ToggleButton>
     <Image Source="image.jpg"/>
</ToggleButton>
```

or any *Panel*, *Button* another *ToggleButton* and so on.

You can also play with its *Style* and *Enabled/Disabled Content*.

Answer (score 1):

First you can try if the AppBarToggleButton fits your needs. It toggles an Icon.

Else, you have to edit the ControlTemplate for the ToggleButton. (In Designer: Right click it, got Edit Template -> Edit a Copy).

The default Template features two content presenters for enabled and disabled content, which you can replace to display your icons.